# В чем смысл передачи аргументов функции справа налево?

Tags: функции, visual-c++

изучая соглашения о вызовах функций (`__stdcall`, `__cdecl`) наткнулся на то, что аргументы функций передаются в стек справа налево. Почему аргументы передаются именно справа налево и никак иначе (за исключением `__fastcall` и `__vectorcall`). Есть этому явлению какое-либо объяснение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порядок не имеет особого значения - ну выбрали, и выбрали, главное - придерживаться его для совместимости.

Однако для `cdecl` с `varargs` этот момент кажется существенным с точки зрения эффективности.

На вершине стека лежит самый первый (левый аргумент), далее второй и т.д.
Таким образом, фиксированные аргументы находятся на известных в момент компиляции смещениях, обращаться к ним легко, быстро, безопасно. Да и для опциональных аргументов смещения тоже просто найти.

Иначе смещения бы приходилось высчитывать, исходя из общего числа аргументов в опциональной `...` части